# Cannot compare strings Python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have some problems comparing Strings/Substring in Python.
Here is my code:

```
spelformer = "V86-1 V75-1 GS75-1".split()
l_count = 0
for line in input:
    print(line.split())
    print(spelformer)
    l_count += 1
    if line in spelformer:
        print("ja")
    else:
        print("nej")
    break
```

This is the result:

```
runfile('G:/Min enhet/Python/Travscript.py', wdir='G:/Min enhet/Python')
['V86-1']
['V86-1', 'V75-1', 'GS75-1']
nej
```

What I can see, line is equal to V86-1 and spelformer is equal to V86-1 and therefore it should be a match. But the results is still "nej" = "no".

Anyone knows why?

Sorry for newbie questions..

Comment: why `break`? It ends the loop after first iteration, always...

Comment: Also...`input` gives you a string (unless you where bold enough to redefine this builtin), the loop iterates over the single characters of this string; also `input` itself should not be iterable, it returns an iterable if used as `input()`...

Comment: Solved it, used .strip(). Some hidden spaces or something in my input file. The "break" was just to end the loop after first line because the file is large and i was testing my ideas. Not needed to test for all lines.

Answer (score 0):

May be you try it this way:

```
spelformer = "V86-1 V75-1 GS75-1".split()
for s in input().split():
    if s in spelformer: print('yes')
    else: print('no')
```

Comment: Solved it with .strip(). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The spelformer string that you are passing is in double quotes (" "), but the string you are passing in input will be taken as single quotes (' '). So, while splitting, the input will be splitted character by character.
Also, the () for input is missing.

Answer (score 0):

if line[0] in spelformer:

This should work as now the string values will be compared. Earlier the list ['V86-1'] was comapared to ['V86-1', 'V75-1', 'GS75-1']. Instead what you need is the string 'V86-1' to be compared to ['V86-1', 'V75-1', 'GS75-1'] as all the elements inside the list is string and not another list.